# C# objects use from javascript in a HTML based webpage

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I am building an Asp Net website in Visual Studio that uses Razor developed HTML pages.  I would like to be able to use some C# from the javascript on one of the web pages (this is not creating a plugin that would be displayed in the browser.)  I have tried to create a simple Cs class that has a single method that returns a fixed string to test this.  The following code is in the ManagedCsClass.cs file is in the App_Code folder in my project.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class ManagedCsClass
{
    public ManagedCsClass()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public string ReturnText()
    {
        return "Text from ManagedCsClass";
    }
}
```

What I am not clear on is where to create the object that would be used by the HTML page (in the same .cs file as the class, another .cs file, or from a call from the HTML browser page).

And what code do I need to use in the javascript to reference the object/method?

Thanks for any help or guidance you can provide.
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use "ActiveX" com objects, this requires the dll containing that class registered on the client and you will have a lot of security/deploy issues ( the client must trust your object and have the framework installed ). It is not the best way to create a web app today.

Comment: Felice, Thanks for the guidance.  Is there any responable way to integrate an HTML site with the use of a more formal language like cs?  Or alternately, there a way to include the cs only on the server and use from the HTML page?

Comment: @Mark try to explore ajax technologies

Comment: Felice, Thanks again.  The getXMLHttpRequest object looks like it will work great on the client side.  can the server side code to respond to the request be written using Visual Studio?  Or Debugged using vs?  If not, do you have a recomendation for me on what tool to use for the server side code?